# I want to use the tailwind and material-tailwind together, but tailwind.config.js overlaps

Tags: css, tailwind-css

As per the title, I was already using the tailwind, but I need to add the material-tailwind to the tailwind.config.js while using the material-tailwind additionally, but I don't know how.

I tried adding to plugin and importing it, but it didn't work out.

Install npm i @material-tailwind/react as indicated in the official document

```
const withMT = require("@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT");
 
module.exports = withMT({
  content: ["./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});
```

I'm trying to add this part, but if I write it in the existing tailwind.config.js, the existing tailwind css won't

Comment: It seems like you may have not finished writing your question? "the existing tailwind css won't" Won't… what?